# Outofmemory error when i display webp image on android 2.x with libwebp and ndk

Tags: android, out-of-memory, webp

I use google open source project libwebp to display webp image on android 1.6--android 4.0,and directly decode webp on android 4.0 or above this version, I found that in some android mobilephones such as appo,I will get an outofmemory error when run libwebp lib,and the code which gives error is:`int[] pixels = new int[decoded.length / 4];` 
can anyone suggest me how to avoid this? Here is my code:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {        
          HttpURLConnection connection = null;        
          Bitmap bmp = null;        
          try {            
               connection = (HttpURLConnection) 
               new URL(src).openConnection();               
               connection.setRequestMethod("GET");           
               connection.setUseCaches(false);            
               connection.setDoInput(true);            
               connection.setDoOutput(true);           
               connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
                   "image/webp");           
               connection.connect();
          //Send request             
               DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (                               connection.getOutputStream ());              
               wr.writeBytes ("");             
               wr.flush ();             
               wr.close ();
              //Get Response                  
               BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];           
             while(true) {               
                  String n = rd.readLine();                
                  if(n == null)break;                
                      baos.write(n.getBytes(), 0, n.getByte().length);                     
                  baos.write('\n');            
           }
            byte data[] = baos.toByteArray();                   
 // From the lib's exemple             
            int[] width = new int[] { 0 };           
            int[] height = new int[] { 0 };
            int test = libwebp.WebPGetInfo(data, data.length, width, height); 
// test = 0 ! ! !
            byte[] decoded = libwebp.WebPDecodeARGB(data, data.length, width, height); 

#######################out of memory error is always here         
            int[] pixels = new int[decoded.length / 4];  
####################### 
            ByteBuffer.wrap(decoded).asIntBuffer().get(pixels);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width[0], height[0],Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);        
             } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using System.gc() before creating bitmaps. This will force to garbage collect in Android. This might free up enough memory. If you keep getting out of memory errors, try to find memory leaks in your code and fix it.

Still not working? Maybe try it in C/C++ in native code. Here you can manage your memory efficiently(if your familiar with C/C++).

Try something like this:

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream getBytesFromURL(String src) {        
      HttpURLConnection connection = null;        
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();       
      try {            
           connection = (HttpURLConnection) 
           new URL(src).openConnection();               
           connection.setRequestMethod("GET");           
           connection.setUseCaches(false);            
           connection.setDoInput(true);            
           connection.setDoOutput(true);           
           connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
               "image/webp");           
           connection.connect();
      //Send request             
           DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (                               connection.getOutputStream ());              
           wr.writeBytes ("");             
           wr.flush ();             
           wr.close ();
          //Get Response                  
           BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));    
           while(true) {               
              String n = rd.readLine();                
              if(n == null)break;                
                  baos.write(n.getBytes(), 0, n.getByte().length);                     
              baos.write('\n');            
           }
           connection.close();
        }catch(Exception q){} //Your exception catching here
           return baos;
}

public static Bitmap createBitmap(ByteArrayOutputStream baos){
            System.gc();
            byte data[] = baos.toByteArray();                   


// From the lib's exemple             
            int[] width = new int[] { 0 };           
            int[] height = new int[] { 0 };
            int test = libwebp.WebPGetInfo(data, data.length, width, height); 
// test = 0 ! ! !
            byte[] decoded = libwebp.WebPDecodeARGB(data, data.length, width, height);        
            int[] pixels = new int[decoded.length / 4];  
            ByteBuffer.wrap(decoded).asIntBuffer().get(pixels);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels, width[0], height[0],Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);        
        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: I try to debug it,the error is always here:int[] pixels = new int[decoded.length / 4];

Comment: and,using system.gc(),bitmap.recycle(),all of these,I have done ,it doesn't work

Comment: It's really hard to help with memory exceptions in any application. You will have to keep the whole application in mind since the memory leak could be anywhere. Also allocations like byte[] buf = new byte[4096]; . Which is never used anywhere takes up memory. Also I would split up the function in what it actually does. First make a connection with the source and get all the data. Then another function to make a BitMap from that source, and dont forget to close the connection.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea,can you type some samples to explain this?thank you.

Answer (score 0):

add attribute android:largeHeap="true" in manifest.xml file inside application tag.If you are using large number of bitmaps in android then use cache concept.Also not forget to recycle the bitmap if you are not using it, anymore.Basically  System.gc() method not works for bitmap.

Comment: thank you for your advise,but my project have set this attribute,it doesn't work,Have you studied the webp lib,how can i reduce the memory consumption by set width and height of decoding webp image,i found that the lib provide the method WebPDecodeARGB(byte[] encoded,int length,int[] width,int[] height)

Comment: added above,what is the role of the last two params:width,height,i considered that width and height were used to set the dimension of decoded webp image,but actually not,how  can i control the dimension of decoded webp image,if i can get a smaller image than the initial image,i believe that i can prevent this error to happen,because smaller bitmap consume much less memory